# Find all unsafe regex in entire NodeJS project

Tags: node.js, regex

How can I find list of all unsafe regex in all project files even in dependency packages in my node.js project?

Comment: Could you define *unsafe regex* ?

Comment: regex which take long time in evaluate an expression or any regex that could be exploited to bridge the system security

Comment: For the former, https://github.com/davisjam/vuln-regex-detector may be suitable. The latter however is completely dependent upon what the project is actually doing.